# Refactoring in Ruby on Rails 4.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I am trying to refactor my code to look cleaner.
Right now I have this *bad* code:

```
@member = Member.new

@member.build_local_board
@member.build_prospective
@member.build_alumni
@member.build_board
@member.build_job
@member.build_academic
@member.build_special_role
@member.build_conferences_member

@prospective = Prospective.new
@alumni = Alumni.new
@board = Board.new
@user = User.new
@job = Job.new
@academic = Academic.new
```

And I was trying to make it similar to this:

```
models = %w(local_board, prospective, alumni, board, [...])
fields = [models]
fields.each do |f|
  @f = f.new
  @member.build_f
end
```

But I think I am missing some ***Ruby syntax***, because I get this error:

`undefined method 'new' for ["local_board,", "prospective"]:Array`

It seems really simple. That's the problem when you first learn the framework and not the core language.

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
models = %w(local_board prospective alumni board)
models.each do |f|
    klass = f.camelize.constantize
    instance_variable_set("@#{f}", klass.new)
  @member.send("build_#{f}".to_sym)
end
```

Try this code.

Comment: **Worked perfectly**, thank you very much. I probably should take a look at the doc. of Ruby to learn all these .camelize, .constantize, .send. Thanks again!